# Difference between synchronized lock on factory Vs lock on class instance?

Tags: multithreading, locking, synchronized, volatile

For creating singleton, usually we use the following static factory method where synchronized lock is on the class itself:

```
private volatile static MyClass instance;
public static MyClass getInstance() throws Exception {
    if(instance == null) {
        synchronized (MyClass.class) {
            if(instance == null) {
                    instance = new MyClass();
            }
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Instead, if we use a factory pattern and put the intrinsic lock on the factory class like:

```
public class MyFactory {
    private volatile static MyClass instance = null;
    public static MyClass getInstance() throws Exception{
        if(instance == null) {
          synchronized (MyFactory.class) {
            if(instance == null) {
                instance = new MyClass();
            }
          }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

---Here the factory pattern code has been simplified to showcase the lock rather than the logic of the pattern.

What will be the difference between putting the lock on the class instance itself Vs on the factory class that creates the instance?

**When the instance is null and multiple threads race to get lock on the factory class Vs the class instance itself**.....will there be any difference/error in the results for getting a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know more about singletons, I recommend that you read [this article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). It will give you a good explanation with nice snippets explaining the various implementations.

Comment: Thanks for the link Craig. I do not no C# but that article was a good read on the various implementations of singleton. The static factory method is the 3rd implementation described in the article which works as the instance variable is has been declared volatile. However my question (edited it now) is on the locking part